# Error in `nano': invalid fastbin entry | Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on GCP

Tags: ubuntu

I'm having an issue I've never had before hence coming to you guys for some help please.

I'm getting the following error when trying to edit a file in nano:

*** Error in `nano': invalid fastbin entry (free): 0x00000000019c35e0 ***
                                                                         ======= Backtrace: =========
                                                                                                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x77725)[0x7f9ff5a7f725]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7ff4a)[0x7f9ff5a87f4a]
                                                          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x82a99)[0x7f9ff5a8aa99]
                                                                                                                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(realloc+0x179)[0x7f9ff5a8bdb9]
                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5(_nc_doalloc+0x13)[0x7f9ff5de00c3]
                                                                                         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5(_nc_tparm_analyze+0x2f7)[0x7f9ff5de3777]
        /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5(tparm+0xbf)[0x7f9ff5de398f]
                                                                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5(vidputs+0x5a1)[0x7f9ff6012de1]
                                                                                                                                            /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5(+0x1da03)[0x7f9ff6017a03]
                                               /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5(+0x1f2e3)[0x7f9ff60192e3]
                                                                                                               /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5(+0x1f9eb)[0x7f9ff60199eb]
                  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5(doupdate+0x29a)[0x7f9ff601b57a]
                                                                                        nano[0x4200be]
                                                                                                      nano[0x4203d2]
                                                                                                                    nano[0x4224fd]
                                                                                                                                  nano[0x422ab8]
                                                                                                                                                nano[0x41619d]
 nano[0x408b4c]
               nano[0x40ccf1]
                             nano[0x40431c]
                                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0)[0x7f9ff5a28830]
                                                                                                                  nano[0x404409]
                                                                                                                                ======= Memory map: ========
                                                                                                                                                            00400000-00432000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 163                                /bin/nano
                                                                                 00631000-00632000 r--p 00031000 08:01 163                                /bin/nano
      00632000-00633000 rw-p 00032000 08:01 163                                /bin/nano
                                                                                        019a3000-01a9a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
          7f9ff0000000-7f9ff0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
                                                          7f9ff0021000-7f9ff4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
                                                                                                          7f9ff4dae000-7f9ff4dc4000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2053                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
                                                         7f9ff4dc4000-7f9ff4fc3000 ---p 00016000 08:01 2053                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
        7f9ff4fc3000-7f9ff4fc4000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 2053                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
                                                                                                                    7f9ff4fc4000-7f9ff4fcf000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2047                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
                                                                          7f9ff4fcf000-7f9ff51ce000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 2047                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
                                7f9ff51ce000-7f9ff51cf000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 2047                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
                                                                                                                                                   7f9ff51cf000-7f9ff51d0000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 2047                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.23.so
                                                                                                         7f9ff51d0000-7f9ff51d6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
                                                                                                                                                         7f9ff51d6000-7f9ff51e1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2044                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
                                                                                                             7f9ff51e1000-7f9ff53e0000 ---p 0000b000 08:01 2044                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
                                                                 7f9ff53e0000-7f9ff53e1000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 2044                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
                     7f9ff53e1000-7f9ff53e2000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 2044                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.23.so
                                                                                                                                      7f9ff53e2000-7f9ff53f8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2042                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
                                                                                      7f9ff53f8000-7f9ff55f7000 ---p 00016000 08:01 2042                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
                                      7f9ff55f7000-7f9ff55f8000 r--p 00015000 08:01 2042                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
                                                                                                                                                   7f9ff55f8000-7f9ff55f9000 rw-p 00016000 08:01 2042                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.23.so
                                                                                                   7f9ff55f9000-7f9ff55fb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
                                                                                                                                                   7f9ff55fb000-7f9ff5603000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2040                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
                                                                                                          7f9ff5603000-7f9ff5802000 ---p 00008000 08:01 2040                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
                                                                 7f9ff5802000-7f9ff5803000 r--p 00007000 08:01 2040                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
                        7f9ff5803000-7f9ff5804000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 2040                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.23.so
                                                                                                                                            7f9ff5804000-7f9ff5807000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2102                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
                                                                                           7f9ff5807000-7f9ff5a06000 ---p 00003000 08:01 2102                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
                                          7f9ff5a06000-7f9ff5a07000 r--p 00002000 08:01 2102                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
                                                                                                                                                      7f9ff5a07000-7f9ff5a08000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 2102                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.23.so
                                                                                                     7f9ff5a08000-7f9ff5bc8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2101                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
                                                   7f9ff5bc8000-7f9ff5dc7000 ---p 001c0000 08:01 2101                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
 7f9ff5dc7000-7f9ff5dcb000 r--p 001bf000 08:01 2101                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
                                                                                                            7f9ff5dcb000-7f9ff5dcd000 rw-p 001c3000 08:01 2101                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
                                                          7f9ff5dcd000-7f9ff5dd1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
                                                                                                          7f9ff5dd1000-7f9ff5df6000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2133 
                      /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
                                                           7f9ff5df6000-7f9ff5ff5000 ---p 00025000 08:01 2133                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib
tinfo.so.5.9
            7f9ff5ff5000-7f9ff5ff9000 r--p 00024000 08:01 2133                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
                                                                                                                          7f9ff5ff9000-7f9ff5ffa000 rw-p 0002
8000 08:01 2133                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
                                                                           7f9ff5ffa000-7f9ff6027000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2054                       /lib/x86_
64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5.9
                               7f9ff6027000-7f9ff6227000 ---p 0002d000 08:01 2054                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5.9
                                                                                                                                                7f9ff6227000-
7f9ff6228000 r--p 0002d000 08:01 2054                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5.9
                                                                                                    7f9ff6228000-7f9ff6229000 rw-p 0002e000 08:01 2054
                /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncursesw.so.5.9
                                                        7f9ff6229000-7f9ff624f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2097                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.2
3.so
    7f9ff62a3000-7f9ff62aa000 r--s 00000000 08:01 24842                      /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
                                                                                                                                7f9ff62aa000-7f9ff6442000 r--
p 00000000 08:01 27718                      /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
                                                                          7f9ff6442000-7f9ff6446000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
                                                                                                                          7f9ff644b000-7f9ff644e000 rw-p 0000
0000 00:00 0 
             7f9ff644e000-7f9ff644f000 r--p 00025000 08:01 2097                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
                                                                                                                      7f9ff644f000-7f9ff6450000 rw-p 00026000
 08:01 2097                       /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.23.so
                                                                  7f9ff6450000-7f9ff6451000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
                                                                                                                  7ffe32610000-7ffe32631000 rw-p 00000000 00:
00 0                          [stack]
                                     7ffe3277b000-7ffe3277d000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
                                                                                                                    7ffe3277d000-7ffe3277f000 r-xp 00000000 0
0:00 0                          [vdso]
                                      ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
                                                                                                                         Aborted (core dumped)

It seems that the file is still in use or wasn't closed down properly (according to vague info I gleaned from Google). I was editing this file through nano yesterday and had no problems.

I'm not sure how this came about as I've been editing files in nano for quite some time and have never come across this before. The problem herein is that I really need to make changes to this file and cannot access it in nano (can sftp but would rather get this sorted out as I normally nano through choice!).

I restart the instance and then try to edit the file again, in which case nano tells me the same as above.

I cannot find a solution to this. I hope you guys can help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I see the question is older, but today I ran into the same issue.

Trying to open the file with VIM, I got the warning that another program may be editing the same file, starting with:

> Found a swap file by the name "file.swp"

After deleting the file using:

> sudo rm -f file.swp

I was able to open it again in nano.